# Issues with building Android native executable programs through CMake and arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc

Tags: android, c++, linux, cmake

CMakeLists.txt

```
STRING( REGEX REPLACE ".*/(.*)" "\\1" CURRENT_FOLDER ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} )
SET(TARGET ${CURRENT_FOLDER})

PROJECT (${TARGET})

add_compile_options(-static -march=armv7-a)

aux_source_directory(./src SRCS)

add_executable(${TARGET} ${SRCS})
```

hello.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("hello ARM!!!");
    
    return 0;
}
```

```
adb push '.\Desktop\hello' /data/local/tmp
adb shell chmod 777 /data/local/tmp/hello
adb shell /data/local/tmp/hello

/system/bin/sh: /data/local/tmp/hello: No such file or directory


adb shell ls -l /data/local/tmp/

-rwxrwxrwx root     root        10652 2021-01-21 17:03 hello
```

When I compile by the following command

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static  -march=armv7-a hello.c -o hello
adb push '.\Desktop\hello' /data/local/tmp
adb shell chmod 777 /data/local/tmp/hello
adb shell /data/local/tmp/hello

hello ARM!!!
```

I found that the compile_commands.json generated by cmake is

```
"command": "/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-8   -g -static -march=armv7-a -o CMakeFiles/hello.dir/src/hello.c.o -c /home/dev/workspace/ASM/Projects/hello/src/hello.c",
```

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem?

Comment: CMake generated 
`arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-8   -g -static -march=armv7-a hello.c.o -c hello.c`
Actually useful
`arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static  -march=armv7-a hello.c -o hello`

Answer (score 0):

CMake use two steps to generate executable. The first step it compiles the source files ( c or c++) to object file. then it links the file needed to generate the executable(s).

The `compile_commands.json` will contain only the commands used to compile and not to link. normally you can find the command used to link in `link.txt`. this file can be found in `CMakeFiles/<name>.dir/link.txt`.

You can also , directly run your make commad with `VERBOSE=1` to see the executed command on live.

For your problem, i think there is a problem with your TARGET variable, but without more information i can not be sure.